# Wordpress wp_enqueue_script() and jQuery in footer

Tags: jquery, footer

I try to load jQuery in my parent template. It works but loading in header despite set to true to last parameter. Placed my wp_head() in both templates.
When I put some jQuery in my main.js (which is loading in footer), it does work. But I have some issues with gravity forms and google Recaptcha because jquery is in header. Here is my code in my parent template:

````
{
    wp_register_style('reset', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/reset.css', []);
    wp_register_style('fontawesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css', []);
    wp_register_style('graphandco', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles/style.css', []);


    wp_register_script('gsap', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js', [], false, true);
    wp_register_script('graphandco', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', []);

    wp_enqueue_style('reset');
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome');
    wp_enqueue_style('graphandco');

    wp_enqueue_script('gsap');
    wp_enqueue_script('graphandco', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}


add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'graphandco_register_assets');```

Thanks in advance !
````

Answer (score 0):

First read about [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/).

You do not need to deregister or register jQuery in the `functions.php` file. because WordPress uses jQuery itself.

Whenever you are adding JS which is depending on jQuery then you can just add third parameter of `jquery` in `wp_enqueue_script()` function. and in the last parameter you have to add `true` so it will load in the footer. Check the below example.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'JS-NAME', 'JS-FILE-PATH', array('jquery'), 'VERSION', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for feeding back, I removed the register and enqueue of the jquery, but jquery is not loading anymore, even in the header. My main.js does not require jquery but it is for testing and got '$ is not a function'. Also grecaptcha.render is not a function.
 

    ``    wp_register_script('graphandco', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), false, true);``

Comment: My mistake. You need to enqueue the script. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: But still need to register first I assume ? with all parameters ?

Comment: No, you don't need to register that If you direct enqueue the script with all parameters.

Comment: I removed the register part, everything is broken even the style.
wp_enqueue_script('graphandco', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), false, true);

Comment: I'm just telling that if you are register your style or script with wp_register_script() then you have to enqueue them with wp_enqueue_script().